# Sort data based on date picked (Android)

Tags: android, date

I have a calendar icon in ActionBar that will allow user to pick a date and shows the files stored on that date in listview.I'm using DatePicker and I need to store the date selected into a variable,so that the date can be sent to a function that will retrieve data for that date.My problem now is when I selected a date,it shows the data from previous selected date.

For example,
First picked date: 2015-05-01 
Second picked date:2015-05-02--listview shows all files for first picked date
Third picked date:2015-05-03 --listview shows all files for second picked date

Below is my code

//call method setDateField()onCreate

```
    private void setDateField() {

     Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
               sdate=(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime())).toString();
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_sort) { 
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
            Set_Date_Data(sdate);//sending the date chosen to sort function
             return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Set_Date_Data(sdate);` inside `onOptionsItemSelected` method. So it does the sorting when you click on sort button, Which would show `fromDatePickerDialog` but apply sorting with old date. You should call `Set_Date_Data(sdate);` inside `onDateSet` listener like this:

```
private void setDateField() {

 Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
           sdate=(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime())).toString();
           Set_Date_Data(sdate);//sending the date chosen to sort function
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

}

Secondly why are you creating a new calendar instance everytime, You can just declare it on class level and re-use it like this:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

private void setDateField() {
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, 
               new OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
                      int dayOfMonth) {
        mCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
       sdate=(dateFormatter.format(mCalendar.getTime())).toString();
       Set_Date_Data(sdate);//sending the date chosen to sort function
    }

},mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_sort) { 
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
         return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```